# Custom Button appears in full screen instead of at the bottom corner

Tags: android, xml, button, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I tried to build a hovering CircleButton (in the right bottom corner) in an existing xml, but the CircleButton appears i nfull screen instead of small, in the right bottom corner.
I tried all sort of things...
I think it has something to do with the RelativeLayout, but I can't manage to let it work!

this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_notities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cb_color="@color/primary"
    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"
    android:minWidth="64dp" />

<!--<Button-->
<!--android:id="@+id/button"-->
<!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
<!--android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"-->
<!--android:text="New note" />-->
```

I need some help please...

Comment: are you trying to create something like Floating Action Button??

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--<include-->
        <!--layout="@layout/app_bar_notities"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:minWidth="64dp"
        android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:cb_color="@color/primary"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for this example! I tweeked it a little and now it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Notities">

<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cb_color="@color/primary"
    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"
    android:minWidth="64dp"
    android:minHeight="64dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_notities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--<Button-->
<!--android:id="@+id/button"-->
<!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
<!--android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"-->
<!--android:text="New note" />-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```